# UICollectionView Cell Scroll to centre

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using UICollectionView in my UIViewController.

My collectionview properties are set as below.

[image]

Now I would like cell to be Centre on screen after scroll!
Option 1:

[image]

Option 2:
[image]

What would I have to do achieve option 2?

**UPDATE:**

In the end I have used following code as scrolling with other answer is not smooth.

```
  - (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
{    CGFloat offsetAdjustment = MAXFLOAT;
    CGFloat horizontalCenter = proposedContentOffset.x + (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.bounds) / 2.0);

    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(proposedContentOffset.x, 0.0, self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
    NSArray* array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:targetRect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* layoutAttributes in array) {
        CGFloat itemHorizontalCenter = layoutAttributes.center.x;

        if (ABS(itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter) < ABS(offsetAdjustment)) {
            offsetAdjustment = itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter;
        }
    }    
    return CGPointMake(proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, proposedContentOffset.y);
}
```

Comment: Cool. And it's better with this line: 
`self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;`

Comment: hello i need UICollectionView Cell Scroll to left side, what shold i do for it??

Comment: Your Update works great! thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:` method in your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass and calculate your offset there like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat previousOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentPage;

...

- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity {
    NSInteger itemsCount = [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

    // Imitating paging behaviour
    // Check previous offset and scroll direction
    if ((self.previousOffset > self.collectionView.contentOffset.x) && (velocity.x < 0.0f)) {
        self.currentPage = MAX(self.currentPage - 1, 0);
    } else if ((self.previousOffset < self.collectionView.contentOffset.x) && (velocity.x > 0.0f)) {
        self.currentPage = MIN(self.currentPage + 1, itemsCount - 1);
    }

    // Update offset by using item size + spacing
    CGFloat updatedOffset = (self.itemSize.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing) * self.currentPage;
    self.previousOffset = updatedOffset;

    return CGPointMake(updatedOffset, proposedContentOffset.y);
}
```

**EDIT**: thanks for pointing this out, forgot to say that you have to disable paging first:

```
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = NO;
```

**UPDATE**: attaching Swift 4.2 version

```
...
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
...

class YourCollectionLayoutSubclass: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    private var previousOffset: CGFloat = 0
    private var currentPage: Int = 0

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
        }

        let itemsCount = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

        // Imitating paging behaviour
        // Check previous offset and scroll direction
        if previousOffset > collectionView.contentOffset.x && velocity.x < 0 {
            currentPage = max(currentPage - 1, 0)
        } else if previousOffset < collectionView.contentOffset.x && velocity.x > 0 {
            currentPage = min(currentPage + 1, itemsCount - 1)
        }

        // Update offset by using item size + spacing
        let updatedOffset = (itemSize.width + minimumInteritemSpacing) * CGFloat(currentPage)
        previousOffset = updatedOffset

        return CGPoint(x: updatedOffset, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it working!! It did not have [self.myCollectionView setPagingEnabled:NO];

Comment: You rock bro! This works, stops the collection view cells in the center of the screen.

Comment: What is self.itemSize.width and  self.minimumInteritemSpacing here ??

Comment: These are width of your collection view cell and spacing between cells.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 11):

you can use code
`self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Swift 3 version of @dmitry-zhukov (thanks btw!)

```
class PagedCollectionLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var previousOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var currentPage : CGFloat = 0

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        let sup = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)

        guard
            let validCollection = collectionView,
            let dataSource = validCollection.dataSource
            else { return sup }

        let itemsCount = dataSource.collectionView(validCollection, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)

        // Imitating paging behaviour
        // Check previous offset and scroll direction
        if  (previousOffset > validCollection.contentOffset.x) && (velocity.x < 0) {
            currentPage = max(currentPage - 1, 0)
        }
        else if (previousOffset < validCollection.contentOffset.x) && (velocity.x > 0) {
            currentPage = min(currentPage + 1, CGFloat(itemsCount - 1))
        }

        // Update offset by using item size + spacing
        let updatedOffset = ((itemSize.width + minimumInteritemSpacing) * currentPage)
        self.previousOffset = updatedOffset

        let updatedPoint = CGPoint(x: updatedOffset, y: proposedContentOffset.y)

        return updatedPoint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found a lot of information and solutions.

now, I use this.

on UICollectionViewFlowLayout override:

```
override public func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    if display != .inline {
        return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
    }

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
    }

    let willtoNextX: CGFloat

    if proposedContentOffset.x <= 0 || collectionView.contentOffset == proposedContentOffset {
        willtoNextX = proposedContentOffset.x
    } else {

        let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width
        willtoNextX = collectionView.contentOffset.x + (velocity.x > 0 ?  width : -width)
    }

    let targetRect = CGRect(x: willtoNextX, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)

    var offsetAdjustCoefficient = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

    let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.contentInset.left

    let layoutAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)

    layoutAttributesArray?.forEach({ (layoutAttributes) in
        let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
        if fabsf(Float(itemOffset - horizontalOffset)) < fabsf(Float(offsetAdjustCoefficient)) {
            offsetAdjustCoefficient = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
        }
    })

    return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustCoefficient, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
}
```

and on UICollectionViewController:

```
collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
```

now, cell is in center!!

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPz4.gif)

Comment: and collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false

Comment: Instead of commenting you can edit your answer and add if any information missed.

Comment: what is display here?

Answer (score 3):

After setting proper `itemSize`, `left` and `right` insets I prefer doing this rather than subclassing layout

```
//Setting decelerationRate to fast gives a nice experience
collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast

//Add this to your view anywhere
func centerCell () {
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: collectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionView.frame.midX, y: 100)
    if let path = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint) {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: path, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}

//Set collectionView.delegate = self then add below funcs
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   centerCell()
}
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerCell()
}
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        centerCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that with itemspacing, sometimes the centerCell method will not be triggered unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why everybody's answer is so complicated, I simply turn on `Paging enabled` in Interface Builder and it works perfectly.

Comment: For none interface builder you can simply set using `isPagingEnabled` on a `UICollectionView` object.

Comment: This is correct, isPagingEnabled is a UIScrollView property which can be set through the interface builder. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619432-ispagingenabled

Comment: The reason other people's answers are so complicated in contrast to yours is that `isPagingEnabled` makes the collectionView scroll across its entire bounds: in the question you can clearly see that the querent wants to scroll through each item and keep them centred, but not across the entire bounds of the collection view. (Which is the behaviour indicated in the *Option 1* screenshots.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for scrolling like paging.

```
//
collectionview.isPaging = false
//

class CollectionLayoutSubclass: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        var point = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return point
        }
        let cells = collectionView.visibleCells
        let centerPoint = collectionView.center
        var cellFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero
        for cell in cells {
            cellFrame = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
            var newCenterPoint: CGPoint = centerPoint
            if velocity.x > 0 {
                newCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x * 1.5, y: centerPoint.y)
            } else if velocity.x < 0 {
                newCenterPoint = CGPoint(x: centerPoint.x * 0.5, y: centerPoint.y)
            }
            guard cellFrame.contains(newCenterPoint) else {
                continue
            }
            let x = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - cell.frame.width / 2
            point.x = cell.frame.origin.x - x
            break
        }
        return point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from an answer from another question:

### Here is my implementation

```
func snapToNearestCell(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     let middlePoint = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x + UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
     if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: middlePoint, y: 0)) {
          self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
     }
}
```

Implement your **scroll view delegates** like this

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    self.snapToNearestCell(scrollView: scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.snapToNearestCell(scrollView: scrollView)
}
```

Also, for better snapping

```
self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```